# Using sed/awk to print ONLY words that contains matched pattern - Words starting with /pattern/ or Ending with /pattern/

Tags: sed

I have the following output:

```
junos-vmx-x86-64-21.1R1.11.qcow2 metadata-usb-fpc0.img metadata-usb-fpc10.img 
metadata-usb-fpc11.img metadata-usb-fpc1.img metadata-usb-fpc2.img metadata-usb-fpc3.img 
metadata-usb-fpc4.img metadata-usb-fpc5.img metadata-usb-fpc6.img metadata-usb-fpc7.img 
metadata-usb-fpc8.img metadata-usb-fpc9.img metadata-usb-re0.img metadata-usb-re1.img 
metadata-usb-re.img metadata-usb-service-pic-10g.img metadata-usb-service-pic-2g.img 
metadata-usb-service-pic-4g.img vFPC-20210211.img vmxhdd.img
```

**The output came from the following script:**

`images_fld=$(for i in $(ls "$DIRNAME_IMG"); do echo ${i%%/}; done)`

The previous output is saved in a variable called `images_fld=`

**Problem:**

I need to extract the values of `junos-vmx-x86-64-21.1R1.11.qcow2`
`vFPC-20210211.img` and `vmxhdd.img` When I mean values I mean the entire word

The problem is that this directory containing all the files is always being updated, and new files are added constantly, which means that I can not rely on the line number ($N) to extract the name of those files.

I am trying to use `awk` or `sed` to achieve this.

Is there a way to:

1. match all files ending with`.qcow2` and then extract the full file name? Like: `junos-vmx-x86-64-21.1R1.11.qcow2`
2. match all files starting with`vFPC` and then extract the full file name? Like: `vFPC-20210211.img`
3. match all files starting with`vmxhdd` and then extract the full file name? Like: `vmxhdd.img`

I am using those patterns as those file names tend to change names according to each version I am deploying. But the patterns like: `.qcow2` or `vFPC` or `vmxhdd`always remain the same regardless, so for that reason, I need to extract the entire string only by matching partial patterns. Is it possible? Thanks!

**Note:** I can not rely on files ending with `.img` as there are quite a lot of them, so it would make it more difficult to extract the specific file names :/

Comment: `I have the following output:` where does the output come from? What generates it? `need to extract the values of` Are these keys? What do you mean by "extract"? in what way? `Is there a way to` Yes. Replace space with newline, and then use `grep`. You want to do all three conditions simultaneously on a continuously updated file? Sooo just `tail -f file | tr ' ' '\n' | grep '\.qcow2$\|vFPC\|vmxhdd'`?

Comment: I have added the script from where the output came from. The values mentioned are the strings or lines from the output :)! If you can see the output, it have quite a lot of files, I just need to "extract" or display only those 3 files mentioned. Could you tell me how can I achieve this by using grep? I tried using grep before but the output was blank :/

Comment: `The output came from the following script:` but why? Are you asking XY question? You presented a list with words - but you do not care about words. Do you want to find newly created files in a directory that match certain filenames? Why do you care about some list of words?

Comment: `"extract" or display only those 3 files mentioned` To display _only those 3 files mentioned_ just `echo junos-vmx-x86-64-21.1R1.11.qcow2 vFPC-20210211.img vmxhdd.img`. Could you be more specific what do you want to achieve exactly? You stated `that this file is always being updated` - how is this file updated? What file - you stated that you have a variable.

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is, from the list of words on the output, extract only specific files from there. That directory containing all of those files is updated constantly so there will be more files added to it. I just need to extract the name of the 3 files that I am looking for. Why? because when there is a new version the name of those 3 files will change. the only remaining string that will not change from those values are .qcow2 vmxhdd and vFPC

Comment: From the output, only extract the files that end with .qcow2 | starts with: vFPC and vmxhdd. and then display the full name of those files, if that makes sense?

Comment: Wait, tail -f file | tr ' ' '\n' | grep '\.qcow2$\|vFPC\|vmxhdd' worked.... wow... that simple? I was overcomplicating myself! so there was no need of awk or sed... wow

Comment: I got an output of (junos-vmx-x86-64-21.1R1.11.qcow2 vFPC-20210211.img vmxhdd.img) ! Thank you! omg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE '/\<\S+\.qcow2\>|\<(vFPC|vmxhdd)\S+\>/{s//\n&\n/;s/[^\n]*\n//;P;D}' file
```

If a string matches the required criteria, delimit it by newlines.

Delete up to and including the first newline.

Print/delete the first line and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [KamilCuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamilcuk) I was able to solve the problem. Thank you! For anyone who may need this in the future, instead of using `sed` or `awk` the solution was by using `tail`.

```
echo $images_fld | tail -f | tr ' ' '\n' | grep '\.qcow2$\|vFPC\|vmxhdd')
```

Basically, the problem that I was having was only to extract the names of the files ending with .qcow2 | and starting with vFPC & vmxhdd

Thank you [KamilCuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamilcuk)

**Another solution** given by [potong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/967492/potong) is by using

```
echo $images_fld sed -nE '/\<\S+\.qcow2\>|\<(vFPC|vmxhdd)\S+\>/{s//\n&\n/;s/[^\n]*\n//;P;D}'
```

which gives the same output as KamilCuk's! Thanks both